# HTML: What exactly is <span>'s purpose?

Tags: html

I've read many explanations of what the actual purpose of the < span > tag is, and I've tried to incorperate those explanations into real applications but have failed every time.

One person told me that it was to apply classes to sub-tags below it, which does kind of work, except it doesn't apply dimensions to elements, unless you mess around with the display and/or inline settings, which can totally screw up a layout.

Then someone else told me that it's use as a substitute for the < div > tag, which doesn't work because floats or "margin: auto"-type attributes don't work unless contained inside certain types of elements.

Then someone else told me that it's used as a text container, which doesn't work because the "text-align" attribute doesn't work, again, unless contained inside certain types of elements. A default-attribute-cleared < p > tag is much more suited, in my experience.

So what exactly is the point of them? Why are so many people using them when < div > seems to do everything that they're apparently capable of and more?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[From Official Docs:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-SPAN)

> The DIV and SPAN elements, in conjunction with the id and class
>   attributes, offer a generic mechanism for adding **structure** to
>   documents. These elements define content to be **inline (SPAN)** or
>   block-level (DIV) but impose no other presentational idioms on the
>   content. Thus, authors may use these elements in conjunction with
>   **style sheets, the lang attribute, etc**., to tailor HTML to their own
>   needs and tastes.

As it says, you can use `<span>` tag to *structure* (inline) the sections of page along with *styling* which you may optionally pass via id, class or stylesheets.

Characteristics of `<span>` tag:

- It's display is `inline` by default which means:

  - you can not apply `width` to it
  - you can not apply `height` to it
  - you can make it block-level too by using `display:block` (`div` serves the same purpose)

The `<div>` tag is opposite to that and you can apply above rules to it.

Comment: background [applies to: all elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background), and since it is "default" the other bullet points apply only until you change that.

Comment: Making something display: block just renders it like a block-level element, it doesn't turn it into one (which is significant because you aren't changing what elements it is allowed to contain, for instance)

Comment: @Quentin: Agreed, that's why I have added `div serves the same purpose`

Comment: But in my, somewhat limited, experience, all you have to do is apply a "float: left;" to a div and it becomes inline anyway? But as you said, you can just apply "display: block;" and it serves the same purpose as a div then.

Seems like they just do the same thing and it's personal preference.

Comment: @BenHooper: Use the tag that is provided rather than converting them :) Also floating left does not make element inline eg you can apply width, etc still :)

Comment: Thank you. :) #commentLengthener

Answer (score 8):

It is an inline element with no attached semantics that can be used to wrap some inline content for

- the application of JavaScript (e.g. event handlers or moving about the DOM)
- the application of CSS
- use with the `lang` attribute
- processing by custom tools

… when no element with more appropriate semantics exists.

> floats or "margin: auto"-type attributes don't work unless contained inside certain types of elements.

They work (or otherwise) based mostly on the `display` value, not the element type.

> Why are so many people using them when `<div>` seems to do everything that they're apparently capable of and more?

A div is identical to a span except it:

- Can contain block elements
- **Cannot** (error recovery not withstanding) be contained by an inline element (or any other element that can contain only inline content, such as a `<p>`)
- Is `display: block` by default (instead of `inline`)

Comment: It seems that you can apply attributes/properties to either tag to make them more like the other. So, is there an winner out of the two? One that is more suited generally than the other?

Comment: @BenHooper Yes! `<div>` is definitely more suitable, if you need a block. `<span>` is the clear winner if you need an inline element. Period.

Comment: Both you and Sarfraz gave an excellent answer, but I have awarded him the correct answer, because he has a much lower score than you, so I think it would be more fair. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

When the text is in a `<span>` element you can add styles to the content, or manipulate the content.